# Cannot modify read only directory on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, google-drive-api

I am trying to write a code on PyCharm and want to put on a file on Google drive folder. However, I tried to create a new file on Google drive on PyCharm, it says that

> "cannot modify a read only directory".

How can I change this setting in order to create Python file in the shared folder?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: it says it is read only.Problem is not about pycharm i think.

Comment: Im on windows. yeah i think it about google drive... but I do not know how to change the setting...

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a known issue. Essentially, there's a problem with windows flags.

I do use version control, but I like to keep some projects on drive for various reasons. I wrote this Powershell script which seems to have done the trick for me:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\user\Google Drive' -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    attrib -r +s $file.FullName
}
```